# Почему ругается Mobx а контент не выводиться?

Tags: api, typescript, mobx

/-----------------"**Это store**"--------------------------/

```
import { runInAction, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
import { getComics } from "../Api/comics/comics";
import { IComics } from "../types/comics";

class ComicsStore {
    comicsList: IComics[] = [];

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setComicsList = () => {
        runInAction(async () => {
            try {
                const {data} = await getComics();
                this.comicsList = data.results
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
};
```

/----------------------**Это Контент**------------------------------/

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite';
import comicsStore from '../../store/comicsStore';
import react, {useEffect} from 'react'

const Comics:React.FC = () => {
    
    const {comicsList, setComicsList} = comicsStore;

    useEffect(() => {
        setComicsList();
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            {comicsList.map(({id, images, title}) => (
                <div key={id}>
                    <div>{images}</div>
                    <div>{title}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(Comics);
```

/-------------------**Ошибка**------------------------/

> derivation.ts:144 [MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: ComicsStore@1.comicsList

Comment: что ты экспортируешь в `/store/comicsStore`?

Comment: привет! если ты про export default comicsStor то он там есть. видимо не скопировалось когда код переносил.

Comment: да про него, доперенеси

Answer (score 0):

Неверно используется метод [`runInAction`](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#runinaction)

Данный метод не должен принимать `async` функцию, он должен внутри нее вызываться:

```
(async () => {

    try {
        const {data} = await getComics();
        runInAction(()=>this.comicsList = data.results);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```